# Set new value for nouislider is reached max number

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

Good day,

Is it possible to set a predefined string value to this if the slider reached maximum value of 2000.

Here's my code

```js
noUiSlider.create(connectSlider, {
 start: 300,
 step: 5,
 connect: 'lower',
 range: {
   'min': 0,
   'max': 2000
 },
 format: wNumb({
  decimals: 0,
  thousand: ',',
  prefix: '$',
  postfix: ' per month',
 }),
});
```

http://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-options/

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `edit` function in the formatter. It runs *after* all other formatting options are applied.

```
format: wNumb({
    decimals: 0,
    thousand: ',',
    prefix: '$',
    postfix: ' per month',
    edit: function ( value ) {
        return value == yourMaxValue ? 'Maximum reached!' : value;
    }
})
```

For reference: [all formatting options](http://refreshless.com/wnumb/options/).